# NuGet 3.5 / Visual Studio 2015 - Change package cache location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

Is it possible to change the nuget package cache path from `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages` to a custom location?

I tried using the environment variable NuGetCachePath, but it doesn't seem to work with it.

Comment: You can use the registry-based policy: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/06/09/redirect-the-package-cache-using-registry-based-policy/

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the location of the package cache by setting an environment variable named `NUGET_PACKAGES`.

For example, change your location from `C:\Users\Frank\.nuget\packages` to `F:\Users\Frank\.nuget\packages` by setting the latter value to a "system" environment variable named `NUGET_PACKAGES`, and rebooting.

Reference: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1905

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to change this for now. The "NuGetCachePath" environment variable you mentioned is for a modified version to work with MonoDevelop on Linux: [mrward/nuget](https://github.com/mrward/nuget).

Comment: Will it works if I set a symlink (mklink) for this folder onto another drive?

Comment: Symlink works sometimes, but I do get occasional "Object not set to reference" errors on the commandline.

Answer (score -1):

I found a setting which should do the trick, the config file that is required to be modified is `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` ([Config File Documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file)).

But there seems to be a catch, as changing the repositoryPath also means that the HintPath of the .csproj is no longer correct (at least for non .net core projects). And as the .csproj most likely is added to version control this is really a big problem.

Here is the setting required to change/add to the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="D:\Cache\NuGet2\packages" />
    </config>
    <!-- More settings follow -->
```

Comment: This does not work, NuGet will happily revert it to the value it was before.